# Array in foreach for ACF field conditional logic?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

In Advanced Custom Fields I have an option page with a repeater field. Within the repeater field I have a DATE FIELD and a SESSION FIELD.

A date (datepicker) can be any COMING DAY.
A session (select field) can be LUNCH or DINNER.

Within this option page I can disable DATES in combination with SESSIONS to disable bookings.

F.i.:

When I set 20-06-2020 as DATE + LUNCH as session >> Customers are unable to book a table for lunch on the 20th of June. Dinner though can still be booked.

My code below does that exact... Except for 1 small (most important) part:

The code only uses the last repeater field row in the option page as field condition. All the earlier date/session combi's are getting ignored.

F.I.

When I have 4 date/session combi's the fields HTML output still only shows the last like this:

```
data-conditions="[[{"field":"field_5ed4181bd63dc","operator":"==","value":"1"},{"field":"field_5ed4178dd63d7","operator":"!=","value":"20200627"}],[]]"
```

This probably has something to do with a missing foreach or something but the last weeks I got lost and I'm almost on the moment to give up :(

Can somebody please help me?

```
// Apply conditions to fields
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=bookings_field_time_session_1', 'yl_check_booking_exeptions_session_1');
function yl_check_booking_exeptions_session_1( $field ) {

    // Retrieve option values. Date value should be like: 20200611 (unformatted)
    $rows = get_field('bookings_settings_disabled_exceptions', 'bookings');

    if( $rows ) {

        foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
            $option_date = get_sub_field('bookings_settings_disabled_date', 'bookings', false);
            $date = date_i18n('Ymd', strtotime($option_date));
            $session = get_sub_field('bookings_settings_disabled_session', 'bookings', false);

            $arrays =
                array(
                    array(
                        'field'     => 'field_5ed4181bd63dc', // Time field session 1 in the form
                        'operator'  => '!=', // If Value is different, then show the field
                        'value'     => $session, // Compare against option page value
                    ),
                    array(
                        'field'     => 'field_5ed4178dd63d7', // Datepicker fiels in the form
                        'operator'  => '!=', // If Value is different, then show the field
                        'value'     => $date, // Compare against option page value
                    )
                );
            }

            if ( $session == '1' ) {
                $field['conditional_logic'] = array(
                    $arrays
                );
            }
        }

        // Return
        return $field;

    }

}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$field['conditional_logic']` every time you are in the foreach.. that is why you only get the last entry ( `where $session == '1'` )  in the foreach loop.

Comment: Yeah I thought something like that was going on but my problem is the fact that my PHP knowledge is not reaching to this level (arrays). I know its probably a longshot but are you willing to copy/paste my code the right way? Thanks for your help.